# Docker container with my java-app fails with standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error"

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes

My own app dockerized on my MacOS M1 Silicon host machine, fails with `standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error"` when launched on Kubernetes cluster, with runs on Linux server.

I have my app with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim as jdkbase
FROM jdkbase
COPY app/target/dependency-jars /run/dependency-jars
COPY app/target/resources /run/resources
ADD app/target/app-1.0.3.jar /run/app-1.0.3.jar

CMD java -jar run/app-1.0.3.jar
```

,this docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  myapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: myapp/Dockerfile
    hostname: myapphost
```

and this pod.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp-container
    image: my.private.repo/app_dir/myapp:1.0.3
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: st-creds
```

I've spent several hours trying to figure it out how to solve it, trying to use diff. variants of Entrypoints and cmds, but non of this was a working option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final solution was to build app for certain architecture, adding  platform (`platform: linux/amd64`) to the compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  myapp:
    platform: linux/amd64
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: myapp/Dockerfile
    hostname: myapphost
```

and also to change base image in the Dockerfile to any java image, which works with amd64, for example, to `amd64/openjdk:11-slim`, like this:

```
FROM amd64/openjdk:11-slim as jdkbase
FROM jdkbase
COPY app/target/dependency-jars /run/dependency-jars
COPY app/target/resources /run/resources
ADD app/target/app-1.0.3.jar /run/app-1.0.3.jar

CMD java -jar run/app-1.0.3.jar
```

Hope this'll save time to anyone else who is new to Docker as me